# Firefox "forget site" functionality or add-on

Tags: firefox, web-development, cookies

Does there exist any add-on for Firefox for selectively removing history (cache, cookies) for certain sites only?

This would be useful for web development to clear the browser state regarding the site under a test.

Web Developer add-on has Clear current domain cookies functionality, but the add-on has not been updated since Firefox 4.

Comment: Do you mean this Web Developer addon? https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/

I've been using it pretty much daily and am on latest firefox version... Very much supported.

Comment: Aeo: why not make that an answer?

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner I probably should... Thanks for pointing that out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been using an addon, also called [Web Developer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/), for my daily job. I don't know if it's what you are using, but it has the functionality you describe. Mayhaps it's an updated version?

Comment: Not available for Firefox 11.0, as stated in the question

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa I see no statement in the question about Firefox 11, and the current version of Firefox is 10 according to the "release" channel (http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/all.html). You may wish to specify this.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `tools - start private browsing`

> In a Private Browsing session, Firefox won't keep any browser history,
>   search history, download history, web form history, cookies, or
>   temporary internet files.  However, files you download and bookmarks
>   you make will be kept.

Comment: This works equally as well, if not moreso in my opinion. :) Even doesn't require yet another add-on. Bonus! :)

Comment: Thanks. I am well aware of private browsing option, but that's not what I am lookign for.